# com.google.ads.adview failed to instantiate cause of Admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I just got a error after I installed Admob on my App.
In a way its weird... I can run my app and my ad is also shown but in
the Graphical Layout View . He tells me this :

```
   The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
    See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

When I take a look in the Error Log it says :

```
com.google.ads.adview failed to instantiate
```

My Code

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/lined2"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="MY ID"
       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
       ads:testdevices="TEST_EMULATOR" >
   </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Someone got a Idea ?
Can I ignore this ?

Comment: maybe It's abstract or singlton, try AdView.getInstance() insteat of new AdView()

Comment: nope :/ Noone got a Idea ?